# Green background on some directories [Oh My Zsh, Zsh]

Tags: macos, terminal, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I have a problem with my terminal / VS Code integrated terminal. When I'm changing directory some directories are with a green background and it's annoying. And I don't know how to disable it. I know that in `.zshrc` I can disable colors in ls with `DISABLE_LS_COLORS="true"` but this is not working with `cd` command.

In the default terminal, it is relatively readable, but in VS Code it is unreadable. Any help?

[image: terminal]
[image: VS Code]

Answer (score 17):

Add the following line to your `.zshrc` file

`export LS_COLORS="$LS_COLORS:ow=1;34:tw=1;34:"`

save the file and then run

`source ~/.zshrc`

Comment: What does this do? Can you explain?

Comment: @PatrickPrakash it hides the annoying green background on dir listing on your terminal

Comment: That's not i have meant., like how does this works. What's this ow, tw means?. Anyway i did a quick google search and found the answer. Thanks btw

Comment: This happens because `oh-my-zsh` highlights folders that have write permissions for group `other`. Instead of removing the highlighting in your `.zshrc` file, you could also set the permissions to, e.g., `755` (read+execute for everyone, write only for owner).

Answer (score 0):

You could just change it for vs code and over ride any theme by changing the settings.json file in settings --> search for workbench --> click edit in settings.json under colour customisations. This should override any theme present from any other add-ons or external terminal mods. I have not tested it before with zshrc though.

In the brackets enter something like this:

```
"terminal.foreground": "#839496",
"terminal.background": "#002833",
"terminal.ansiBlack": "#003541",
"terminal.ansiBlue": "#268bd2",
    "terminal.ansiCyan": "#2aa198",
    "terminal.ansiGreen": "#859901",
    "terminal.ansiMagenta": "#d33682",
    "terminal.ansiRed": "#dc322f",
    "terminal.ansiWhite": "#eee8d5",
    "terminal.ansiYellow": "#b58901",
    "terminal.ansiBrightBlack": "#586e75",
    "terminal.ansiBrightBlue": "#839496",
    "terminal.ansiBrightCyan": "#93a1a1",
    "terminal.ansiBrightGreen": "#586e75",
    "terminal.ansiBrightMagenta": "#6c6ec6",
    "terminal.ansiBrightRed": "#cb4b16",
    "terminal.ansiBrightWhite": "#fdf6e3",
    "terminal.ansiBrightYellow": "#657b83",
    "terminalCursor.foreground": "#839496",
    "terminalCursor.background": "#003541"
```

Comment: But I will override the default `"terminal.ansiGreen": "#98c379"`. This is not the desired solution because this will broke terminal color rendering in other situations.